# Can I breakdown CPQ Quote Calculator Plugin (QCP) into multiple files and just call them from one custom script?

Tags: cpq-plugins

We're using QCP for many products to meet our needs. It's getting a bit unmanageable because of the amount of lines of codeand it's only going to get bigger. Is there a way to split these files and call on them/import/include them from the QCP Plugin file that is pasted into a custom script? If so, where do I store those files?
Thank you in advance for all help